# Shortcut to create New Message from non-default account Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2010 I have 3 email accounts setup, the "New E-Mail" button creates a new email from the default account. I would like to be able to create a new message for the other 2 accounts at the click of a button, rather than now where I create a new message and then change the from address.

Part of the reason I want to be able to do this is I want to automatically add a signature to emails being sent from 1 of the 3 addresses. It doesn't get added when I change the from address once I've created a new email.